# Use constructor function execute prototype methods structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function($){
    'use strict';

    var ezAutoSuggestion = function( selector, href ){
        return new init(selector, href);
    };

    //construct
    var init = function( selector, href ){

        defaults.call(this);

        //property
        this.element = $(selector);
        this.href = href;
        this.inputText = $(selector + " input[type='text']" );
        this.inputText.after(this.suggestionList);
        this.list = $(selector + " ul");
        this.choosen = selector + " li";

        //method    
        this.getDatas();
        this.hideList();    
        this.choose();  
    };

    //method
    init.prototype.getDatas = function(){
        //post input keyup value and get data from backend
    };

    init.prototype.choose = function(){
        //add user's choose into input text
    };

    init.prototype.hideList = function(){
        //user click blank area hide auto suggestion
    };

    window.ezAutoSuggestion = ezAutoSuggestion;

})(jQuery);
```

I'm new in writing javascript plugin, I wrote a simple auto suggestion plugin and I have put on github MIT licence for people to download it.

My question is

First I create a `construct function,` and inside of my constructor I set up `properties` and than `start call methods`. (I also borrow jQuery's idea user function to create a `new init object`, so user don't need to type new)

Is this good way to do? or are any better way to structure this?

here is my github links
https://github.com/yben56/ez-auto-suggestion

Comment: After having a quick look I'd say that the word 'data' is already plural. Other than that this question requires for opinionated answers which is kind of against the setup of StackOverflow and might not help you in finding the best solution for you. Is there any specific problem you're encountering at the moment?

Comment: i just not sure use constructor call methods is good way to do it or not or are any better way to structure it